# Why does __new__ not have classmethod decorator

Tags: python

Why doesn't the `new` method have a class decorator on it? For example:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

How is this method able to act as a `classmethod` without having that decorator on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's specifically special-cased. `type.__new__` will apply `staticmethod` automatically when creating your class if it sees that you defined a `__new__` without applying `staticmethod`. (Also, `__new__` is supposed to be a `staticmethod`, not a `classmethod`.)

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> Called to create a new instance of class *cls*. `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument...

and the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L2705):

```c
    /* Special-case __new__: if it's a plain function,
       make it a static function */
    tmp = _PyDict_GetItemId(dict, &PyId___new__);
    if (tmp != NULL && PyFunction_Check(tmp)) {
        tmp = PyStaticMethod_New(tmp);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            goto error;
        if (_PyDict_SetItemId(dict, &PyId___new__, tmp) < 0) {
            Py_DECREF(tmp);
            goto error;
        }
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }
```